# Possible to use abstract property value in a Base class's method?

Tags: c#

If I create an abstract property in my C# Base class, and then a subclass implements it, is it possible to then reference and use that property in one of my Base class's methods later on once the subclass sets that property?

I want to sort of pass a value from my subclass to base class so that in my base class I can perform some logic using it in that Base class method.

Or even not a property but an field instead...same idea...but I would need to require that field to be set in a subclass if the case..don't think that's even possible?  I don't really need a property if I can set some sort of flag in my subclass via an abstract field so that the base class can use that flag for some logic that my subclass is going to depend on such as sending an HttpRequest.

Basically I want to be able to set a flag in any subclasses using this base to say true or false so that the Base class's SendRequest method knows whether to chose from a couple of URIs that I have set in my base class.  That flag will determine which format to use in the base class's SendRequest method since each subclass will vary in terms of what URI format the base class should use for that subclass in order to send the HttpRequest on behalf of the subclass.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, that is basically the whole purpose of abstract properties and methods.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like something like this will work:

```
class Base
{
    protected Boolean Flag { get; set; }

    public void Foo()
    {
        if (this.Flag)
        {
            // logic here
        }
    }
}

class Child : Base
{
    public Child()
    {
        // you can set Flag anywhere you wish
        this.Flag = true;
    }
}
```

I don't think you need anything to be `abstract`.  You can set `Flag` in the child type and then check it in either type for conditional logic.

Comment: Yes indeed. The property would only need to be abstract if the derived classes implemented the storage for the property in some sophisticated way, e.g. one uses the registry, another uses a database, another uses a plain field in memory, etc.